# Heroku Procfile with node executable in bin directory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, procfile

I have a node application that serves up my angular application from root directory from wwwroot directory.  My executable to start this app is in bin/www.js.  My Procfile is web: node bin/www.js

I cannot get it to serve the application on Heroku.  Any ideas on why this is happening.  It has something to due with structure but I cannot figure out why this is an issue.  My build pack is nodejs.

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVkNV.png)

Image of my directory structure

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the Procfile to web: node ./bin/www.js  ?

Also can you display Heroku's build log from when you attempt to deploy?

Comment: let me do now.  I didn't even think of relative paths.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: I did provide everything asked by the answer provided above.  I could not include logs in a comment so I used pastebin

Comment: Another approach might be to use your package.json in lieu of the Procfile like so:                                                                                                          {
  "name": "heroku-node",
  "description": "your heroku app",
  "main": "./bin/www.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...(your dependencies here)
  }
}